# osmosis --used-node keyword does not grab all relevant nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, pbf

I am trying to filter an osm.pbf file using osmosis. The following is my filter:

```
osmosis
  --read-pbf-fast metadata-unfiltered.osm.pbf workers=8
  --tf accept-ways <placeholder>
  --tf reject-relations 
  --used-node 
  --write-pbf output.osm.pbf
```

I have an issue with the `--used-node` keyword. It is supposed to accept nodes that are contained in ways. But when I look at the output file, I do not find all the nodes that are used in the ways that I am grabbing. Some are missing and they are definitely in the input file. Do you know what the issue is or what I could look at? Did I configure the filter correctly?